# Simulate mouse click inside QWebView in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qwebview, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to simulate a mouse click inside a `QWebView`

My code:

```
QMouseEvent eve( (QEvent::MouseMove), QPoint(10,10),
     Qt::NoButton,
     Qt::NoButton,
     Qt::NoModifier);

ui->webView->setMouseTracking(true);

qApp->sendEvent(ui->webView, &eve);
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set mouse position before the click by :

```
QCursor::setPos(mapToGlobal(ui->webView->pos()+=QPoint(10,10)));
```

Also mouse click simulation could be done by :

```
QMouseEvent * event1 = new QMouseEvent ((QEvent::MouseButtonPress), QPoint(10,10),
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::NoModifier   );

qApp->postEvent((QObject*)ui->webView,(QEvent *)event1);

QMouseEvent * event2 = new QMouseEvent ((QEvent::MouseButtonRelease), QPoint(10,10),
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::NoModifier   );

qApp->postEvent((QObject*)ui->webView,(QEvent *)event2);
```

Comment: does that count 10x10 inside the webView? i want the click to be done 10x10 inside the actual webView

Comment: Yeah it will send the click event to the position (10,10) of webView.